# What is the easiest shape for a Haar Cascade to detect?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I need to detect a symbol in an image.  The symbol can be of my design, with the only requirement is that it be printable on a regular sheet of paper.

What type of features does Haar pick up best?  Should I be using high contrast lines (black/white) or should there be a gradient?  Are curved lines better than straight ones?

Comment: What else is on the page? Can your symbol be colour? Why do you think you need a Haar cascade?

Comment: * Its a picture of a granite slab, with some other things in the background (mostly a wall).   

*It can be color.

*I am doing this in python/opencv.  I looked for how to train for object detection, and Haar is what I found.  I am locked into opencv, but not Haar.

Comment: This may help... http://stackoverflow.com/q/43404255/2836621